# Determine whether this relation is reflexive, symmetric, antisymmetric and/or transitive?

Tags: relations

R is defined on $\mathbb{N} × \mathbb{N}$  by $(a, b)R(c, d)$ iff $a \leq c$ and $b \leq d$.

I think it's reflexive and transitive. Not too sure about it being symmetric or antisymmetric.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Try a few examples. Do you have $(1,2)R(3,4)$? What about $(3,4)R(1,2)$? What does that tell you?

Comment: Not symmetric. It's just antisymmetry that's got me confused.

Comment: Ok, so suppose $(a,b)R(c,d)$ and $(c,d)R(a,b)$ are both true. What does that tell you?

Comment: ...Not antisymmetric?

Comment: What does antisymmetric mean? It means that if $(a,b)R(c,d)$ and $(c,d)R(a,b)$ then $(a,b)=(c,d)$. Is that true here?

Comment: That's exactly what I'm confused about, though. I don't quite get antisymmetry.

Comment: So from what I understood it's antisymmetric then? I'm new to this, sorry.

Comment: You are correct! Now you can enter your solution as an answer!

Comment: Haha, alrighty then. Thank you very much. :)